# My Flutter code adds a row by button click, but the new row is not being displayed. Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: flutter

I searched on this in this forum, but nothing came up for Flutter specifically.
I'm using the flutter_expandable_table package and I just can't see how to add a row to a table by button click so that it is displayed on the emulator screen in Android Studio IDE.

I'm using the controller suggestion on the package website.
I've spent hours on this and can't see how to make it work.
Any help is appreciated. Here is the code (it's short).
Code:

```
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_expandable_table/flutter_expandable_table.dart';
        
    const Color primaryColor = Color(0xFF1e2f36); //corner
    const TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.white);
        
    void main() {
        runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Expandable Table Example',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: const MyHomePage(),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyHomePage({super.key});
    
      @override
      State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class DefaultCellCard extends StatelessWidget {
      final Widget child;
    
      const DefaultCellCard({
        super.key,
        required this.child,
      });
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          color: primaryColor,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
          child: child,
        );
      }
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      late ExpandableTableController controller;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        controller = ExpandableTableController(
          firstHeaderCell: _buildCell('Database Tree'),
          headers: [
            ExpandableTableHeader(
              cell: _buildCell('#Trained'),
            ),
            ExpandableTableHeader(
              cell: _buildCell('Score'),
            ),
            ExpandableTableHeader(
              cell: _buildCell('#Positions'),
            ),
          ],
          rows: [
            ExpandableTableRow(
              height: 20.0,
              firstCell: _buildCell('Overall Stats'),
              cells: [
                _buildCell('0/0'),
                _buildCell('0.0'),
                _buildCell('0'),
              ],
            ),
          ],
          headerHeight: 20,
          defaultsColumnWidth: 72,
          firstColumnWidth: 150,
          scrollShadowColor: Colors.black,
        );
    
        super.initState();
      }
    
      void _onEvent() {
        setState(() {
          controller.rows.add(
            ExpandableTableRow(
              height: 20.0,
              firstCell: _buildCell('VCoco'),
              cells: [
                _buildCell('0/0'),
                _buildCell('0.0'),
                _buildCell('0'),
              ],
            ),
          );
    
          if (kDebugMode) {
            var numRows = controller.rows.length;
            print('Row length = $numRows');
          }
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Expandable Table Example'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: _onEvent,
                  child: const Text('Add Row'),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ExpandableTable(
                    controller: controller,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      _buildCell(String content, {CellBuilder? builder}) {
        return ExpandableTableCell(
          child: builder != null
              ? null
              : DefaultCellCard(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      content,
                      style: textStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
          builder: builder,
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_expandable_table/flutter_expandable_table.dart';
import 'package:synchronized/extension.dart';

const Color primaryColor = Color(0xFF1e2f36); //corner
const TextStyle textStyle = TextStyle(color: Colors.white);

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Expandable Table Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class DefaultCellCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  const DefaultCellCard({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: primaryColor,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
      child: child,
    );
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late ExpandableTableController controller;
  List<ExpandableTableRow>  rows = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = ExpandableTableController(
      firstHeaderCell: _buildCell('Database Tree'),
      headers: [
        ExpandableTableHeader(
          cell: _buildCell('#Trained'),
        ),
        ExpandableTableHeader(
          cell: _buildCell('Score'),
        ),
        ExpandableTableHeader(
          cell: _buildCell('#Positions'),
        ),
      ],
      rows: [
        ExpandableTableRow(
          height: 20.0,
          firstCell: _buildCell('Overall Stats'),
          cells: [
            _buildCell('0/0'),
            _buildCell('0.0'),
            _buildCell('0'),
          ],
        ),
      ],
      headerHeight: 20,
      defaultsColumnWidth: 72,
      firstColumnWidth: 150,
      scrollShadowColor: Colors.black,
    );

    super.initState();
    rows = [
      ExpandableTableRow(
        height: 20.0,
        firstCell: _buildCell('VCoco'),
        cells: [
          _buildCell('0/0'),
          _buildCell('0.0'),
          _buildCell('0'),
        ],
      ),
    ];
  }



  void _onEvent() {

    setState(() {
      rows.add(
        ExpandableTableRow(
          height: 20.0,
          firstCell: _buildCell('VCoco'),
          cells: [
            _buildCell('0/0'),
            _buildCell('0.0'),
            _buildCell('0'),
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
    controller.rows = rows;
    if (kDebugMode) {
      var numRows = controller.rows.length;
      print('Row length = $numRows');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Expandable Table Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _onEvent,
              child: const Text('Add Row'),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ExpandableTable(
                controller: controller,
                rows: rows,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _buildCell(String content, {CellBuilder? builder}) {
    return ExpandableTableCell(
      child: builder != null
          ? null
          : DefaultCellCard(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            content,
            style: textStyle,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      builder: builder,
    );
  }
}
```

Try changing the code to this

Comment: I just found out about `notifyListeners`, you can simply add `controller.notifyListeners();` after `controller.rows.add` to achieve the refresh, without needing to write the code I mentioned earlier.